# Why is my footer covering up all my main content when I resize my screen to mobile except my nav

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

When I resize my screen to mobile view my footer just covers all my content with no scroll bar and no matter how tall I make the window it is still covering all of the content. And another weird thing is it is not covering my navigation menu when it's covering the content instead. I have tried other posts but couldn't find something useful.

#### snippet to my website

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(69, 69, 69, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-con {
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.sid-bar {
  border: dotted;
  background-color: burlywood;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .main-con,
  .sid-bar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #111;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .content p,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .content .box {
  width: 33%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

footer .content .topic {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .content p {
  text-align: justify;
}

footer .content .lower .topic {
  margin: 24px 0 5px 0;
}

footer .content .lower i {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

footer .content .middle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

footer .content .middle a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

footer .content input[type="text"] {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
}

footer .content input[type="submit"] {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #eb2f06;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #eb2f06;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 0;
}

footer .bottom a {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

@media (max-width:1100px) {
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  footer .content .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .content {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:560px) {
  footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  footer .content .box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <title>The Random Stuff Blog - A Blog That Is About - Ramdom Topics - Free For All</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    <a href="articles.html" title="Articles">Articles</a>
    <a href="about.html" title="About">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="main-con" title="Main Content">
    <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sid-bar" title="Side Bar">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left box">
        <div class="upper">
          <div class="topic">About us</div>
          <p>The Random stuff blog is all about intresting random stuff that you might need, we post once a week and is constently being updated.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">
          <div class="topic">Contact us</div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>###-###-####</a>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>jw5929001696@gmail.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle box">
        <div class="topic">Our Articles</div>
        <div><a href="#">Coding</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Life</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Crafts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Facts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Education and Laarning</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">More!</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Copyright © 2022 <a href="index.html">The Random stuff blog</a> All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's working with mobile preview. My solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kind of went through and cleaned up the whole thing. It appears you were trying hard to solve the issue with your use of media queries. I went through and removed all of them. Sometimes less code is better code.

With that being said, the main thing I did to make it more responsive was split the two `main-con` sections into their own respective divs. Doing this will give you more styling possibilities and ease of manipulation on certain parts of your markup. So with both sections in their own div, remove the `float` so you can flex the parent and make width 100%. After that, make the two children `width: 50%;` so it fulls the entire screen. Finally, you can declare a height on your parent element.

Once you have adjusted the responsiveness of `main-con`, you can simply fix the footer by using `position: relative;` instead of fixed.

Edit ~ you should add your height and width to the `html` as well as the `body`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(69, 69, 69, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-con {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-con>div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.sid-bar {
  border: dotted;
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #111;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .content p,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .content .box {
  width: 33%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

footer .content .topic {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .content p {
  text-align: justify;
}

footer .content .lower .topic {
  margin: 24px 0 5px 0;
}

footer .content .lower i {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

footer .content .middle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

footer .content .middle a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

footer .content input[type="text"] {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
}

footer .content input[type="submit"] {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #eb2f06;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #eb2f06;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 0;
}

footer .bottom a {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <title>The Random Stuff Blog - A Blog That Is About - Ramdom Topics - Free For All</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    <a href="articles.html" title="Articles">Articles</a>
    <a href="about.html" title="About">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="main-con" title="Main Content">
    <div>
      <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sid-bar" title="Side Bar">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left box">
        <div class="upper">
          <div class="topic">About us</div>
          <p>The Random stuff blog is all about intresting random stuff that you might need, we post once a week and is constently being updated.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">
          <div class="topic">Contact us</div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>###-###-####</a>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>jw5929001696@gmail.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle box">
        <div class="topic">Our Articles</div>
        <div><a href="#">Coding</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Life</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Crafts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Facts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Education and Laarning</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">More!</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Copyright © 2022 <a href="index.html">The Random stuff blog</a> All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked but now that this got done when I change the `sid-bar` to `width: 30%;`. it does not work

Comment: @thecocoman Were you able to figure it out? I just got back, and can look into it if you still need.

Comment: Not yet I was also taking a break going to the bathroom and eating lunch just got back.

Comment: @thecocoman see adjustments. I made it the `background-color: crimson;` on the first child div to `main-con`. I target it in CSS using `.main-con > div:nth-child(1)` then split the two divs up 70 and 30.

Answer (score -1):

Don't fix the footer as in position. Here is the Codepen that I made for you.

```
https://codepen.io/ash_000001/pen/OJOQLGV?editors=1100
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(69, 69, 69, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent{
  
}
.main-con {
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
  background-color: crimson;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height 100px;
}

.sid-bar {
  border: dotted;
  background-color: burlywood;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 520px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .main-con,
  .sid-bar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #111;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .content p,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .content .box {
  max-width: 33%;
  width:100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

footer .content .topic {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .content p {
  text-align: justify;
}

footer .content .lower .topic {
  margin: 24px 0 5px 0;
}

footer .content .lower i {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

footer .content .middle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

footer .content .middle a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

footer .content input[type="text"] {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
}

footer .content input[type="submit"] {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #eb2f06;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #eb2f06;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .bottom {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 0;
}

footer .bottom p{
  text-align:center;
}



footer .bottom a {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

@media (max-width:1100px) {
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  footer .content .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .content {
    margin-top: 40px;
    
  }
}

@media (min-width:560px) {
  footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    
    
  }

@media (max-width:560px) {
  
  footer .content .box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
  <title>The Random Stuff Blog - A Blog That Is About - Ramdom Topics - Free For All</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
    <a href="articles.html" title="Articles">Articles</a>
    <a href="about.html" title="About">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="main-con" title="Main Content">
    <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sid-bar" title="Side Bar">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left box">
        <div class="upper">
          <div class="topic">About us</div>
          <p>The Random stuff blog is all about intresting random stuff that you might need, we post once a week and is constently being updated.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">
          <div class="topic">Contact us</div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>###-###-####</a>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>jw5929001696@gmail.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle box">
        <div class="topic">Our Articles</div>
        <div><a href="#">Coding</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Life</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Crafts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Facts</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Education and Laarning</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">More!</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Copyright © 2022 <a href="index.html">The Random stuff blog</a> All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```